# Terraform state mv

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a `terraform` module from which i am creating 3 servers in `azure`, in `var` file i am specifying the `instance type` of the servers that are being created from this module, now i want to change the instance type of one of the 3 servers, is there a `terraform` way of achieving this, or should i manually upgrade the instance type and then use `terraform state mv` for only that particular server, i am not sure , does `state mv` take `size` argument as well? Any help on this would be appreciated,

```
terraform plan -target=module.serverset.azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.new_vm[2]"
```

In the above line, i am just targeting the specific server, is that the right way of doing it? , because in `vars` file i am changing the `instance type` which will be taken for all servers, after i do this what will happen to the same module which has other 2 servers in old config

Comment: terraform will do the change for you simply update your terraform where you specify the original server instance type ... terraform is declarative not imperative meaning you declare your desired intentions in terraform code and terraform figures out what must be created or destroyed and recreated based on it doing a check between current reality and what you code says

Comment: in comparison a normal programming language like python, java, golang, etc are all imperative where the computer only does what your code says it does not automatically undo the results of a previous execution simply because you have updated your code ... terraform is declarative in that it will undo the results of a prior run when you update your code to declare a new desired reality

Comment: @ScottStensland my module has already created 3 servers, and i am changing only one server now by changing the vars file which was for all 3 servers, i feel something is missing here

Comment: just run all your various options in test to confirm

Answer (score 0):

> now i want to change the instance type of one of the 3 servers, is
> there a terraform way of achieving this

Using the below command you can check what is going to happen if you do apply the same command:

```
terraform plan -target=module.serverset.azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.new_vm[2]"
```

For example, I created 2 `Standard_B2s` Linux virtual machines in a single file .After creating , I wanted to changed one of the VM to size of `Standard_DS1_v2` . So , using the command  `terraform plan -target="azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.myterraformvm[1]"` it showed what will be changing like below:

[image]

Then using command `terraform apply -target="azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.myterraformvm[1]" -auto-approve`, I changed the same thing and it will get bydefault updated in the state file as well. You can refer below images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

> In the above line, i am just targeting the specific server, is that
> the right way of doing it? , because in vars file i am changing the
> instance type which will be taken for all servers, after i do this
> what will happen to the same module which has other 2 servers in old
> config

As mentioned above , You are correct and it can be done that way as shown in above example .As you are targeting a index module ,It won't be affecting the other two server as I have tested the same and added the output in the example.

Coming to the instance type in var file , It won't be taken for all the servers as you are targeting a specific module index.

Comment: what if i add a new server after i do this, so all 4 servers will be converted to new instance type?

Comment: @windowws, if you add a new server to module but after doing the required change to a existing server in the module then also nothing will be affected as you will be creating it separately and move it to existing module state file by using terraform state mv command.

Answer (score 0):

Because Terraform is a desired-state declarative system rather than an imperative system, the general approach here would be to change the configuration to describe what you want the system to *now* look like, rather than to describe exactly what changes Terraform ought to make.

You seem to have a resource which has [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) set and therefore there are multiple instances of the same resource each with its own index. In other arguments in the `resource` block for that resource you can use `count.index` to refer to the individual index of each instance, which means that you can write a rule for selecting an instance type based on the index. For example:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "new_vm" {
  count = 3

  size = count.index == 2 ? "Standard_DS1_v2" : "Standard_F2"
  # ...
}
```

Exactly matching on a particular index might not be the best rule here, but you can write whatever rule you need to specify which index should have which `size` argument by writing arbitrary Terraform expressions to describe your intended rule.

When you create a plan against your existing infrastructure, the Azure provider will then see that the `size` argument only changed for a subset of the instances of this resource, and so it will only plan to update or replace the ones that changed.